# Cross thread calls vs multiple controls

Tags: winforms, vb.net-2010

I have a Winform GUI that have an UDPClient listener thread working on second plane to avoid halt the GUI; when the thread receive something call a Sub in the WinForm code; that Sub process the data and must to fill different TextBox depending on the received data.

As you know if I try to change the text property of any control from the Sub I will receive a Cross Thread error.
So in order to avoid that I make some delegates for a few control(just a test) and works OK.

But the WinForm have more than 100 controls and I was wondering if there's some way to do it with less code.

Making a search I found this two questions.

[Multi-threaded WPF Application: Dispatcher Invoke. A more efficient way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464038/multi-threaded-wpf-application-dispatcher-invoke-a-more-efficient-way)

[Change WPF controls from a non-main thread using Dispatcher.Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644079/how-can-i-use-the-dispatcher-invoke-in-wpf-change-controls-from-non-main-thread)

On the first link they talk about use Dispacher, something like

```
Public Shared Sub UiInvoke(a As Action)
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(a)
End Sub
```

I wrote that code in my Form but the IDE(VS2010/NET4.0) says that "Current" is not a member.

I think I'm missing something, I never used before or do something similar as Dispacher, I usually use Delegates.

What I'm doing wrong? There's another way to control many controls with one Delegate?
I just need to read or write the text property.

Comment: Start buy not using application.current - there may be more than one dispatcher. get the dispather on the window.

Comment: Are you talking about do something like? 'code'   Public Shared Sub UiInvoke(ByVal a As Action)
        Dispatcher.Invoke(a)
    End Sub 'code'

Comment: Yes. One day you may find code that has multiple UI Threads, each running one or more windows. THis is easily doable, but it makes the concept of a "current" dispatcher on application level a little totally moot.

Comment: Are you using winforms OR WPF? your question is completely unclear. WPF solutions won't work in winforms, and BTW you'd rather not use winforma at all.

Comment: @HighCore - I'm using WinForm, I thought it was the same just called different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anonymous `Sub`s:

```vb
Me.Invoke(
    Sub()
        ' Update controls here
    End Sub)
```

Comment: I wrote the following inside a Private Sub  Me.Invoke(Sub(),Me.UtcDateTxt.Text="140505") and the VS IDE says "
Lambda expressions of a single line statement must contain exactly one instruction"; underline on Sub().

Comment: @E_Blue, I don’t know where you got the comma from. Use exactly as shown.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I read the single quote(') as coma; now is working, thanks.