# Receiving the error: "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ddlReportType' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke, visual-c#-express-2010

Not entirely sure what this error means. In the code below, I am using a FileSystemWatcher to wait for a file with a ".gz" extension to appear in the directory, to which will then perform the "ExtractFile" method. But, I am receiving an error on the line where I declare the "filePath" string saying "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ddlReportType' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on".

I have found some solutions of people using Invoke but I am not sure how to incorporate that into my code. Any help with this will be appreciated. Thank you!

Below is my code:

```
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    public void MyWatcher()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        watcher.Path = "C:\\Reporter";
        watcher.Filter = "*.gz";

        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName
           | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(ExtractFile);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    }

    public void ExtractFile(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

            string filePath = @"C:\Reporter\" + ddlReportType.Text.Substring(0, 1) + "_"
                           + ddlDateType.Text.Substring(0, 1) + "_" + lblVendorID.Text + "_" + txtDate.Text + ".txt.gz";

            string filePath2 = @"C:\Reporter\" + ddlReportType.Text.Substring(0, 1) + "_"
                + ddlDateType.Text.Substring(0, 1) + "_" + lblVendorID.Text + "_" + txtDate.Text + ".txt";


            FileStream sourceFileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
            FileStream destFileStream = File.Create(filePath2);

            GZipStream decompressingStream = new GZipStream(sourceFileStream,
                CompressionMode.Decompress);
            int byteRead;
            while ((byteRead = decompressingStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
                destFileStream.WriteByte((byte)byteRead);
            }

            decompressingStream.Close();
            sourceFileStream.Close();
            destFileStream.Close();

    }
```

Comment: UI controls make for very bad variables

Comment: Hi, you can do it by putting an Invoke around the whole content of your ExtractFile method. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5464091/6439999